# Allow remote computer access to SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, windows-firewall, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016

I have both SQL Server and Windows on version 2016. I am trying to set the firewall to allow SQL Server Management Studio to connect from my PC to it.
I have created an entry for port 1433 TCP local and another entry for the actual sqlsrv.exe application under Inbound Rules.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you configured SQL Server itself to allow remote connections?  Allowing the traffic through your Firewall is only half the equation.

Comment: If I turn off the firewall, it works fine, so no problems on SQL Server side.

Comment: Since it's not clear if you have properly configured your server, I am unable to submit an answer, but [Configure the remote access Server Configuration Option](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: You will need to allow all the ports listed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-2016) more than likely.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned whether you installed a default or a named instance. See [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms165614(v=sql.90)#sql-server-2005-default-and-named-instances) for further details on the difference.

What you have done should work for a default instance `SERVERNAME`, if instead you have installed a named instance `SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME` then you would also need to allow the [SQL Browser Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver15) service. Lookup the path in Windows services for this and while in there ensure that it is set to Startup Type: Automatic and it is started. The default installation path is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe"`

If this doesn't work, ensure that TCP/IP is enabled for the SQL Server in the SQL Configuration Manager.

To summarise:

Default instance `SERVERNAME`:

- Allow the sqlservr.exe or port 1433 if using the default port [through the firewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4525108/security-risks-of-allowing-apps-through-windows-defender-firewall)
- Ensure [TCP/IP is enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-protocols-tab?view=sql-server-ver15) in [SQL Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-configuration-manager-help?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Ensure [Allow Remote Connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMSProcedure) is enabled in SQL Server

Named instance `SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME`:

- Allow the sqlservr.exe [through the firewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4525108/security-risks-of-allowing-apps-through-windows-defender-firewall)
- Allow the sqlbrowser.exe [through the firewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4525108/security-risks-of-allowing-apps-through-windows-defender-firewall)
- Ensure the [SQL Browser Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver15) (sqlbrowser.exe) is started in services
- Ensure [TCP/IP is enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-protocols-tab?view=sql-server-ver15) in [SQL Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-configuration-manager-help?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Ensure [Allow Remote Connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMSProcedure) is enabled in SQL Server